# Where to keep configuration objects for directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a view where I use a directive multiple times. Let say my html looks like this:

```
<my-directive config="config1"></my-directive>
<my-directive config="config2"></my-directive>
<my-directive config="config3"></my-directive>
<my-directive config="config4"></my-directive>
```

config1, config2, etc. are scope variables - objects containing some configuration stuff. Because configX are quite big objects my controller doesn't look nice. I would like to make the controller more simple. I would like to keep this configX object somewhere else. Where should I keep it? In Angular factory injected to controller? Another controller which actual controller extends? Or do you have better solution?

Config objects look like this:

```
    $scope.config1 = {
    value1: "value1",
    value2: "some value",
    value3: "some value 3",
    list: [
         {
             v1: "string string",
             v2: "string string",
             v3: int
         },
         {
             v1: "string string",
             v2: "string string",
             v3: int
         },
         {
             v1: "string string",
             v2: "string string",
             v3: int
          },
          {
             v1: "string string",
             v2: "string string",
             v3: int
          }
]};
```

Comment: can you post your config object? From your message i would suggest, that you write a factory/service

Comment: I posted example config object - the list could have usually 3 - 10 elements. I use 4 - 8 config objects in one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your configs are static, I would store them in some constant that will always return the same data.

```
angular.module("yourApp").constant("configForYourDirective",{
     config1: {
        prop1: "John",
        prop2: "Doe"
     ,
     config2: {
        prop1: "John",
        prop2: "Papa"
     }
});
```

Then, a simple extend will add those configs to your $scope

```
angular.module("yourApp").controller("someController", [
    "$scope",
    "configForYourDirective",
    function($scope, configForYourDirective){
        angular.extend($scope, configForYourDirective);
    }
]);
```

And your template will juste have to look like this :

```
<my-directive config="config1"></my-directive>
<my-directive config="config2"></my-directive>
```

Comment: @latata : Sorry I've written bullshit. If your config is static : use a constant instead of a factory (I've edited my accepted answer)